# File reading and printing then sort by added date

Tags: c

I want to make program that read file name in current directory and sort file name by added date in C programming.
I learned how to print file name by using DIR.
But I can't find any answer how to sort file name from it.(DIR)

Could you please teach me how to solve?

Best regards,

Comment: For the date, look at `fstat()` function

Comment: Thank you for this,
I'll check it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can get the file names. Refer to this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda16keh.aspx
2. sort the string array.

Comment: Is it possible only on visual studio?